# Take in 10 numbers, validate each input, append then in a list and then prints the sum of the list values

Tags: python, python-3.x, validation, error-handling, deque

I'm practicing loops in Python and started trying to have a better approach with user inputs, is there better ways of dealing with inputs when coding?
And I tried using deques too, it worked very well, but don't know if I should or need to; are deques better in this case or should I keep using lists?

```py
sum_numbers: list = list()

for question in range(1, 11):
    while True:
        try:
            print(f'{question}º number: ')
            asnwer = float(input('->  ').strip().replace(',', '.'))
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input! Try again...\n')
            continue
        else:
            sum_numbers.append(asnwer)
            break

print(
    '\nNumbers:\n'
    f'{sum_numbers}\n'.replace('[', '').replace(']', '') +
    f'\nSum: {sum(sum_numbers)}.'
)
```

Comment: Do you intend on supporting comma decimals like `9,263` ?

Comment: @Reinderien I wanted to make sure that even if the user types a number like 9,263 could have the same results as someone typing 9.263. In the script perspective, 9,263 will be read as 9.263 after the ',' is replaced with the '.' to let the code work as intended. But I think that I didn't understood your question, did i answered it correctly?

Comment: Kind of. If I had to guess, your locale is `pt-PT`, whose decimal separator is a comma. I have suggestions on how to better handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*performatic* isn't a word, and in the software development industry this is more frequently written *performant*. Anyway, performance is not at all a concern in this program and you should be more concerned about correctness, maintainability and legibility.

If you're trying to accommodate commas as decimals, that's localisation (L10N). Python has support for localisation, and you should use it.

Consider rewriting your input loop as an iterator function.

`asnwer` is spelled `answer`.

Don't convert a list to a string and then `.replace()` on it - instead `.join()` the sequence with a separator of your choice.

You don't need a `continue`/`else`: you can break right out of the `try`.

### Suggested

```
from locale import atof, format_string, setlocale, LC_ALL
from typing import Iterator


def get_numbers(n: int) -> Iterator[float]:
    for question in range(1, n + 1):
        while True:
            try:
                yield atof(input(f'{question}º número: '))
                break
            except ValueError:
                print('Entrada inválida! Tente novamente...')


def main() -> None:
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt-PT')
    numbers = tuple(get_numbers(10))
    formatted_numbers = ", ".join(
        format_string('%.1f', x) for x in numbers
    )
    print(
        '\nNúmeros:'
        f'\n{formatted_numbers}'
        f'\nSoma: {format_string("%.1f", sum(numbers))}.'
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Output

```
1º número: 7.5
2º número: 3,50
3º número: 4,2
4º número: 5
5º número: 5
6º número: 5
7º número: 5
8º número: 5
9º número: 5
10º número: 5

Números:
7,5, 3,5, 4,2, 5,0, 5,0, 5,0, 5,0, 5,0, 5,0, 5,0
Soma: 50,2.
```

Comment: Thank you, Reinderien. All the tips and the suggested code made me see more clearly the need for study about the code itself and the correct way of spelling or using some words when talking about software development. Getting back to studies right now!